# Flutter: How to extract user account name and video id from a shortened tiktok url?

Tags: flutter, web, web-scraping, flutter-web, url-shortener

I wanted to extract the real tiktok video link but my code seems to not be working. I want to get the
https://www.tiktok.com/@lilymaycreative/video/6911015584570395906?sender_device=pc&sender_web_id=6894321561748211206&is_from_webapp=v

from the shorten link which is
https://vm.tiktok.com/ZSTjLwCK/

```
 var dio =
        Dio(BaseOptions(connectTimeout: 10000, receiveTimeout: 10000, headers: {
      'User-Agent':
          'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
    }));

    try {
      Response response = await dio.get('https://vm.tiktok.com/ZSTjLwCK/');

      _document = parse(response.data);
      if (_document != null) print(_document);

 print(jsonData);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
```

Comment: Use HttpURLConnection to follow the redirected and get the URL bro. I know how to do in Java not in Flutter so...

Comment: @DiLDoST Using HttpURLConnection  in java,getHeaderField("Location") returned only host url e.g www.tiktok.com not full url.Can you help me how can i get full url?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?I need to same solution

Comment: Ok! U r right, sometimes it's showing full link sometimes not. So u can do it using Jsoup bro

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you a way that can help solve your problem.

If you press F12(developer tools) in your example [site](https://vm.tiktok.com/ZSTjLwCK/).

You detect video tag in html like below and you may access the video link.

[image]